# Google Docs Apps Script to find and resize positioned images

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to resize images in a Google Doc using Apps Script. The images are positioned images ( https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/positioned-image) which use text wrapping

The code I'm trying is not finding any positioned images ( and neither is getBody().getImages() ). The images are just copy / pasted from another doc.

This is the code:

```
  function processPositionedImages(width, height) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();

  for (var i = 0; i < body.getNumChildren(); i++) {
    var element = body.getChild(i);
    if (element.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH) {
      var paragraph = element.asParagraph();  // Ensure paragraph object
      var images = paragraph.getPositionedImages();
      Logger.log("Child Type: Paragraph "+ i + " # of positioned images " + images.length)

      processImages(images, width, height);
    } else if (element.getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE) {
      var table = element.asTable();  // Ensure table object
      var images = table.getPositionedImages();
      Logger.log("Child Type: Table"+ i + " # of positioned images " + images.length)
      processImages(images, width, height);
    }
  }
}


// Utility function to process individual images
function processImages(images, width, height) {
  for (var j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
    var image = images[j];
    image.setWidth(width).setHeight(height);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that in your situation when a sample Google Document is provided, it will help users think of the current issue of your script and a solution.